# jQuery resizing with CSS. Why won't this work?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any reason the following code has no effect on font size?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
Test
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('body').css({fontSize:'2em'});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Edit:
I for got the simple link.
This is why I can't have nice things.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, it's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/aLhLX/). You may have not put jQuery there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first try putting a proper `DOCTYPE` then add a link to jQuery, and finally try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').css({'font-size','2em'});
</script>
```

==EXAMPLE==

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Test
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').css({'font-size','2em'});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Micky, He doesn't have to, though I would.